# Using a sub select to count results in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table which includes a list on employees, some of those employees are managers of others in the same table. I have tried searching this online, i tried using joins, count(), sub selects etc. i know i should be using these but i don't know how.[image: My Table]

I want to be able to list all manager which have 5 or more employees, so basically

```
select first_name, last_name
where manager_id has 5 or more occurrences.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IN` clause to find managers that have an `EMPLOYEE_ID` that appears more than 4 times in the `MANAGER_ID` column. I am assuming the table is called `EMPLOYEES` here. The `MANAGER_ID` column stores the `EMPLOYEE_ID` of employees that are managers.

For example:

```
    -- List all manager which have 5 or more employees
    SELECT 
       first_name, 
       last_name
    FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE
    EMPLOYEE_ID IN
    (
       SELECT e.MANAGER_ID 
       FROM EMPLOYEES e
       GROUP BY e.MANAGER_ID 
       HAVING COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) > 4 
    )
```

The `SELECT` within the `IN` clause is using a `GROUP BY` to group the records in the `EMPLOYEES` table by `MANAGER_ID`. The `HAVING` clause will restrict the `MANAGER_ID`s returned to records that have more than 4 employees.

Comment: Thats perfect, i completely forgot about grouping. i was trying to use count in the select with no luck but this makes so much sense now.

Comment: It gives me an error, "Every derived table must have an alias"